# Julia: Updating a Float64 within a function

Tags: julia

I am trying to create a function to update a Float64 argument. The example below should be able to clarify what I am trying to achieve.

```
a=1.2

function fun!(a)
   a=3.4;
end
```

Unfortunately, `a` is updated only in local scope. Is there a way to do it? I thought that passing a pointer to the function could help, but I am not sure how to do it in Julia.

Comment: FWIW you can do `a = Ref(1.2)`, and then `a[] = 3.4` to modify inside the function. This creates [reference](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/base/c/#Core.Ref), which is a garbage-collectable piece of mutable memory (like a 1-element array). There are some good reasons to use Refs, but they shouldn't usually be the first choice, so make sure you need such mutation -- see Chris's answer for background.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this. A `Float64` is not a mutable value, so you cannot mutate the value of `a`. You can only replace `a` by a separate `Float64`. This is what an immutable value is.

More lower level (and usually true, although there are exceptions): `Float64`s are represented by their actual bytes, while mutables are pointers to the actual bytes. The actual value of a mutable is its pointer. Mutating means changing values at the memory location that the pointer is pointing to, but this doesn't exist for the immutable.

Answer (score 3):

To complete the answer and if you have a C/C++ background:

- mutable objects are generally allocated on the heap and have stable memory addresses. They are passed by reference
- immutable objects are on the stack and are passed by copy

Also, AFAIK, the `!` of `fun!` is only a name convention to draw attention it has nothing to do with julia internals. You can write `fun` is you want.

**Examples:**

```
v=ones(3);                         # [1 1 1]
isimmutable(v)                     # false -> v is passed by reference
foo(v::Array{Float64}) = v .*= 2;  # hence v can be modified
foo(v); 
v                                  # [2 2 2]

v=Int(1)                           # 1
isimmutable(v)                     # true -> v is passed by copy
foo(v::Int) = v *= 2               # use a local copy of v
foo(v)                             # returns 2, but it is a local copy
v                                  # 1 (unmodified because we worked with a copy)
```

Also see [FAQ](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/faq/#I-passed-an-argument-x-to-a-function,-modified-it-inside-that-function,-but-on-the-outside,-1)

**Ref{} example:**

Isaiah Norton comment

```
foo(r::Ref{Int}) = r[] *= 2

r=Ref{Int}(1)     # Base.RefValue{Int64}(1)
foo(r);
r                 # Base.RefValue{Int64}(2)
```